# PHP header download (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, header

I have a simple problem. I am trying to make header download (Save as dialog window) to download file from server. My code:

```
public function downloadBill()
{
    $id = Input::get('post_id');
    $db = DB::connection('smsservice');
    $file_ = $db->table('bills')->where('id', $id)->pluck('blob');
    $filename = 'download.txt';
    File::put($filename, base64_decode($file_));

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));


}
```

Save as dialog starts, and I can download file download.txt, but the file is emtpy 0 kb, which draws me to the conclusion that location of download is not equal to the location of the of saved "download.txt". I tried putting file to diferent locations, even on the D:\ disk as well, but I didn't manage to make it work. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Does `File::put()` return false? Also, have you confirmed `$file_` has any data in it? if you `dd($file_) ` does it return data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel has a built-in method for returning a download response. `response()->download($filePath);`. This will handle everything needed for the file to be downloaded, automatically http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#file-downloads

I'd also be inclined to use the `storage_path()` function to save the file into an explicitly known, suitable directory rather than letting PHP save it where it likes.

```
$filename = storage_path(sprintf('/downloads/%s.txt', $id));
```